# Cancel postDelayed within onTextChanged

Tags: java, android

I want make Web service called after by 3 seconds every time you update value of `EditText`, but in case if you update value of `EditText` before 3 seconds, remove all delayed callback and wait for 3 sec for Web Service call.Please see my cod and let me know proper way to do this task

```java
@Override
public void onTextChanged(final CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

    if (s.length() > 2) {

        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
        handler.postDelayed(
                new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        // Soap call

                    }
                },
                3000);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you declare the handler "final Handler handler = new Handler();" outside this scope, so that it should always point to single handler and remove pending and reset.

Comment: create a member variable handler and use handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this code**

It will solve your issue.

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
    final Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            //Soap Call;
        }
    };

    editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {


        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

             handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            handler.postDelayed(runnable, 3000);

        }
    });
```

Comment: pleasure is all mine

Answer (score 0):

Try this .

```
long lastTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
final Handler handler;
public void onTextChanged(final CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    if(s.length() > 2) {
        if (System.currentTimeMillis() - lastTime > 3000) {
            startWork();
        }
        lastTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }
}

public void startWork() {
    if (null == handler) {
       handler = new Handler();
    }
    handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //Soap call
        }
    }, 3000);
}
```